# Nested MvxListView binding failure

Tags: mvvmcross

Is it possible to nest bound MvxListView's (mvvmcross android v3.1 series)?

I'm finding the nested bind fails with:

```
MvxBind:Warning:  1.17 Unable to bind: source property source not found Property:Command on MenuSection
```

Our ViewModel looks a bit like

```
   class SomeViewModel : MvxViewModel{
       public List<MenuSection> Sections{get;set;}
   }
```

where

```
class MenuSection{
   public string Title{get;set;}
   public MenuItem[] Items{get;set;}
}
class MenuItem{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public ICommand Command{get;set;}
}
```

Cutdown version of the axml with most non-mvx attributes removed looks like:

**layout/page_home.axml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>
  <Mvx.MvxListView
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Sections"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_menusection" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**layout/item_menusection.axml**

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView local:MvxBind="Text Title"/>
  <Mvx.MvxListView
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_menusection_item"
      local:MvxBind="ItemSource Items; ItemClick Command" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout/item_menusection_item.axml**

```
<TextView local:MvxBind="Text Name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are binding the inner ListView to MenuSection object.

The Commmand property is in MenuItem object not in MenuSection.

You need to move the Command to MenuSection.

EDIT:

**page_home.axml** is bound to **SomeViewModel** =>

**ListView.Items** is bound to **SomeViewMode.Sections** =>

each item defined in **item_menusection.axml** is bound to a **MenuSection** =>

(in **item_menusection.axml**) **ListView.Items** is bound to **MenuSections.Items** =>

each item defined in **item_menusection_item.axml** is bound to **MenuItem** =>

**TextView.Text** is bound to **MenuItem.Name**

Also in **item_menusection.axml**: **ListView.ItemClick** is bound to **MenuSections.Command** (which it doesn't exist)

This is because how you defined **layout/item_menusection.axml**

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView local:MvxBind="Text Title"/>
  <Mvx.MvxListView
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_menusection_item"
      local:MvxBind="ItemSource Items; ItemClick Command" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Both of ListView's ItemSource and ItemClick are bound **to the same** view-model (MenuSections).

If you want to handle the item click in the MenuItem view-model instead you can do this in few ways:

You can try to make the layout in item_menusection_item clickable and bind the click event to the MenuItem.Command.

Or, add a Command property to MenuSection and just call the Command of the selected MenuItem in turn:

```
public class MenuSection
{
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public MenuItem[] Items{get;set;}    
    public ICommand Command { get { return new MvxCommand<MenuSection>((ms) => ms.Command.Execute(null)); } }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense; MenuSection shouldn't have a command, items in the menu should.

Comment: Secondly, page_home is bound to 'Sections' list in VM; item_menusection is thus binding a MenuSection. So binding 'Items' should work if the object hierarchy is being bound correctly

Comment: no, both ItemSource and ItemClick are bound to the same view-model MenuSection. I edited my response to show the bindings flow.